# System Verilog- Wait statements

Tags: system-verilog

I'm confused about the exact meaning of the wait statement.

What happens in this case:

```
forever begin
    wait (vif.xn_valid == 1'b1);
    @(posedge vif.clk);
end
```

Is the wait statement blocking?  Is the

```
@(posedge vif.clk)
```

executed every time inside the loop, regardless of the evaluation of the wait expression?

And in this case:

```
forever begin
    wait(vif.cyc_tic == 1'b1) @(posedge vif.clk) #0 fact_log2_samp_t = vif.fact_log2_samp;
end
```

Is the code after the wait (`#0 fact_log2_samp_t = vif.fact_log2_samp;`
) executed only if the evaluation of the wait expression is true?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In this case

```
forever begin
    wait (vif.xn_valid == 1'b1);
    @(posedge vif.clk);
end
```

the loop blocks until the expression `(vif.xn_valid == 1'b1)` is true, then it blocks until there is a `posedge` on `vif.clk`.

A `wait` statement blocks until the condition is true. If the condition is already true then execution carries on immediately.

In this case:

```
forever begin
    wait(vif.cyc_tic == 1'b1) @(posedge vif.clk) #0 fact_log2_samp_t = vif.fact_log2_samp;
end
```

the loop blocks until the expression `(vif.cyc_tic == 1'b1)` is true, then it blocks until there is a `posedge` on `vif.clk`. It is the same as:

```
forever begin
    wait(vif.cyc_tic == 1'b1);
    @(posedge vif.clk);
    #0 fact_log2_samp_t = vif.fact_log2_samp;
end
```